# After change ApplicationUser.cs I get error Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I have problem while I try to register new user in Application. Once I modify my `ApplicationUser Model` and `ApplicationDbContext` modify to store UserID as `INT`
Once I run application and navigate to `Register` I get error message

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole`1[System.String]]' while attempting to activate 'CarPlatzz.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
```

What I change in my ApplicationUser is

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }      

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    }
```

And Register.cs

```
namespace CarPlatzz.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> _roleManager;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfwork;


        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> roleManager,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _unitOfwork = unitOfWork;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Ime i prezime")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Polje Ime je obavezno! Molimo vas unesite Vaše Ime i prezime")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
            public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Grad")]
            public string City { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Broj telefona")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Broj telefona je obavezan! Molimo vas unesite Vaše broj telefona ! ")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            public int? ClientId { get; set; }

            public string Role { get; set; }


            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Password {0} mora sadrzati {2} najmanje {1} karakter.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Potvrdi password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password i Potvrdi password nisu isti. Molimo vas unesite isti password")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

            Input = new InputModel()
            {
                ClientList = _unitOfwork.Client.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                }),

                RoleList = _roleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i,
                    Value = i
                }),
            };

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ApplicationUser user = new()
                {
                    UserName = Input.Email,
                    Email = Input.Email,
                    ClientId = Input.ClientId,
                    StreetAddress = Input.StreetAddress,
                    City = Input.City,
                    PostalCode = Input.PostalCode,
                    Name = Input.Name,
                    PhoneNumber = Input.PhoneNumber,
                    Role = Input.Role
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Admin));
                    }

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Manager))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Manager));
                    }

                    // u slucaju da se izbrise admin potrebno je samo obrisati tabelu AspNetUsers i odkomentarisati
                    // ovu liniju
                    //await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Admin);


                    // takodjer potrebno je i ovo zakomentarisati

                    if (user.Role == null)
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, SD.Role_Manager);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, user.Role);
                    }


                    //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    //code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    //var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    //    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    //    pageHandler: null,
                    //    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    //    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (user.Role == null)
                        {
                            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // admin registering new user
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { Area = "Admin" });
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And I change my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
        }
```

I try insted of `IdentityUser` change to inherit from  `ApplicationUser` but still same problem.
Alos I try to change from `IdentityUser` to something like `IdentityUser<int>` but still same problem.
Since here is problem with `RoleManager` also I try to change  `RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> roleManager,` but still same problem. Really I don't understand where I make mistake, what I made wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

After I test application I notice that in my ApplicationDbContext I use `IdentityRole<int>` and because of that I need to change in `RegisterModel.cs`

From this

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<string>> _roleManager;
```

To

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> _roleManager;
```

And `RegisterModel` also

```
public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager,
            IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _unitOfwork = unitOfWork;
        }
```

And OnPost Action

```
if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Admin));
                    }

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Manager))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(SD.Role_Manager));
                       
                    }
```

To

```
 if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Admin))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(SD.Role_Admin));
                    }

                    if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(SD.Role_Manager))
                    {
                        await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<int>(SD.Role_Manager));
                       
                    }
```

After delete Migration Folder and use again

```
Add-Migration Initialize 

Update-Database
```

Register works fine !